# Replicate BBC iPlayer rotation effect with HTML5 / Canvas / JavaScript etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I want to replicate the effect seen [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/console/b00xt54m/Annie_Mac_DJ_Marky_and_Breakage_Mini_Mix) on the BBC iPlayer where various circles and arcs rotate around a point.

I understand I need to use the `Canvas` element along with some drawing code to draw arcs which the have to be rotated.  [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/2_4_canvas_arc.html) is an example of how I have tested drawing arcs. - I discounted the use of CSS3 features as I wasn't sure it'd give me the control I wanted - perhaps I'm wrong?

I'm not sure how to rotate these arcs in a way that mimics the BBC iPlayer.  Ideally I want to create either a preset pattern and rotate various sections or just create a random pattern on the fly.  But either way each section will require it's own rotation speed and so forth.

Can anyone help out with either a quick demo or perhaps some pointers on how to get started on this?

I'd also appreciate any advice on any browser limitations imposed by each solution.  I understand not much will work in IE though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try taking a look at this: [HTML5 Canvas Machines Vortex](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-machines-vortex/).

Comment: I'm really looking forward to when we can do all of that kind of stuff with some consistency across browsers

Comment: It was but a random Google search that came up trumps! I'd be interested to see what your final result is.